Testcontainer - MySqlContainer cannot be accessed when used in Spring Boot project
EDIT I have this problem only with mysql image 8.4.0 and 8.3.0
I've recently found the testcontainer testing framework and I wanted to check it out.
I have a Spring Boot application that is connected to MySql database and MyBatis is used in order to specify the queries.
So I tried writing the test class where I could test mapper's methods:
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class AnglerMapperTest {

    @Container
    @ServiceConnection
    static MySQLContainer<?> mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("mysql:8.4.0"))
            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(180));

    @Autowired
    AnglerMapper anglerMapper;

    @Test
    void connection_established() {
        assertThat(mySQLContainer.isCreated()).isTrue();
        assertThat(mySQLContainer.isRunning()).isTrue();
    }
}

With this configuration, this error occurs every time:
Container is started, but cannot be accessed by (JDBC URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:64856/test), please check container logs
Full logs:
16:54:52.978 [main] INFO org.testcontainers.images.PullPolicy -- Image pull policy will be performed by: DefaultPullPolicy()
16:54:52.993 [main] INFO org.testcontainers.utility.ImageNameSubstitutor -- Image name substitution will be performed by: DefaultImageNameSubstitutor (composite of 'ConfigurationFileImageNameSubstitutor' and 'PrefixingImageNameSubstitutor')
16:54:53.567 [main] INFO org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -- Loaded org.testcontainers.dockerclient.NpipeSocketClientProviderStrategy from ~/.testcontainers.properties, will try it first
16:54:54.107 [main] INFO org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -- Found Docker environment with local Npipe socket (npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine)
16:54:54.109 [main] INFO org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory -- Docker host IP address is localhost
16:54:54.171 [main] INFO org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory -- Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 24.0.2
  API Version: 1.43
  Operating System: Docker Desktop
  Total Memory: 7879 MB
16:54:54.235 [main] INFO tc.testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 -- Creating container for image: testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1
16:54:54.768 [main] INFO org.testcontainers.utility.RegistryAuthLocator -- Credential helper/store (docker-credential-desktop) does not have credentials for https://index.docker.io/v1/
16:54:55.690 [main] INFO tc.testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 -- Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 is starting: 6d401e62f6cb7b4585b8394025fdc2945d11ef203516638c5308344f973b6c9f
16:54:57.448 [main] INFO tc.testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 -- Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 started in PT3.2137023S
16:54:57.466 [main] INFO org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper -- Ryuk started - will monitor and terminate Testcontainers containers on JVM exit
16:54:57.467 [main] INFO org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory -- Checking the system...
16:54:57.468 [main] INFO org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory -- ✔︎ Docker server version should be at least 1.6.0
16:54:57.472 [main] INFO tc.mysql:8.4.0 -- Creating container for image: mysql:8.4.0
16:54:58.826 [main] INFO tc.mysql:8.4.0 -- Container mysql:8.4.0 is starting: a0c3df06c728a724f868e14b8b5eb438e0cd685573e874c60eb6560b35727181
16:55:00.352 [main] INFO tc.mysql:8.4.0 -- Waiting for database connection to become available at jdbc:mysql://localhost:55898/test using query 'SELECT 1'
16:57:00.412 [main] ERROR tc.mysql:8.4.0 -- Could not start container
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Wait strategy failed. Container exited with code 1
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:536)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:357)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:347)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:333)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.start(TestcontainersExtension.java:280)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.access$200(TestcontainersExtension.java:267)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$null$4(TestcontainersExtension.java:82)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$5(NamespacedHierarchicalStore.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore$MemoizingSupplier.computeValue(NamespacedHierarchicalStore.java:372)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(NamespacedHierarchicalStore.java:361)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore$StoredValue.evaluate(NamespacedHierarchicalStore.java:308)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore$StoredValue.access$200(NamespacedHierarchicalStore.java:287)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespacedHierarchicalStore.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$2(NamespaceAwareStore.java:57)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.accessStore(NamespaceAwareStore.java:90)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:57)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$startContainers$5(TestcontainersExtension.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.startContainers(TestcontainersExtension.java:82)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.beforeAll(TestcontainersExtension.java:56)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$12(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:396)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:396)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:85)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:63)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container is started, but cannot be accessed by (JDBC URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:55898/test), please check container logs
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:176)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:503)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not create new connection
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.createConnection(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:262)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.createConnection(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:218)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:158)
    ... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:438)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:189)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.createConnection(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:253)
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

I tried changing .testcontainers.properties file:
#Modified by Testcontainers
#Fri May 10 15:47:34 CEST 2024docker.client.strategy=org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy
ryuk.container.privileged=true
tc.host=127.0.0.1
client.ping.timeout = 600

Also, I tried tuning the container:
    static MySQLContainer<?> mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("mysql:8.4.0"));
//            .waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(".*Ready to accept connections.*\\n", 1))
//            .withStartupCheckStrategy(new IndefiniteWaitOneShotStartupCheckStrategy())
//            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));

But nothing worked. Does Anyone have an idea how to setup MySqlContainer so I can test Mapper's methods.

Quick fix would be downgrading the mysql version. Instead of using 8.4.0 we can use 8.2.0. My further investigation will be to check the release notes and see potential problems.
